# TypeError: Object of type Response is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, sql, json, api, psycopg2

I am trying to use Python and APIs to build an SQL table with the names of the first 100 Pokemon in the Poke API. Here's my code

```py
import psycopg2, json, requests, hidden

# Load secrets
secrets = hidden.secrets()

conn = psycopg2.connect(host=secrets['host'],
        port=secrets['port'],
        database=secrets['database'],
        ...,
        connect_timeout=3)

cur = conn.cursor()

defaulturl = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=100&offset=0'


sql = '''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pokeapi
(id SERIAL, body JSONB); 
'''

cur.execute(sql)

response = requests.get(defaulturl)
js = response.json() 


results = js['results'] 



for x in range(len(results)):
    body = requests.get(results[x]['url'])
    js_body = json.dumps(body) 
    sql = f"INSERT INTO pokeapi (body) VALUES ('{js_body}'::JSONB)";
    cur.execute(sql, (defaulturl))

print('Closing database connection...')
conn.commit()
cur.close()
```

And the error is coming up for this line

`---> 35     js_body = json.dumps(body)`

I'm not sure what's causing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requests.get()` returns the *entire* response, not just the body text.

If you want the body text, use the `text` attribute of the response object:

```
response = requests.get(results[x]['url'])
js_body = json.dumps(response.text)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. I want to get just the names of the first 100 in the column body, this gives the whole JSON line I think.

Comment: @hulio_entredas So, iterate over the entries and stop processing once you reach 100.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: Oh, okay. When I ran a test it didn't look like the SQL table was filling the body column with Pokemon names with this code.

Comment: @hulio_entredas My answer only addressed the json error.  I have no idea if it is filling the SQL table properly.

Comment: Right, makes sense. Sorry about that. Thanks for your help! I just had to change the lines to `js_body = body.text` and `cur.execute(sql, (js_body,))` in the for loop